# ValueInjecter injecting between models with same property names

Tags: mapping, viewmodel, valueinjecter

I am trying to inject properties from `ProductCategoryViewModel`, which has `Title` and `Id` properties into `ProductViewModel`, which also has `Title` and `Id` properties (but for Product) and `ProductCategoryTitle`,`ProductCategoryId` for `ProductCategory`.

Nothing I tried so far works. The default injection overwrites `Title` and `Id` props in `ProductViewModel` and so does `FlatLoopValueInjection`.

This is such a common use case, is there a premade value injection for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this using the following value injection

```
    public class ProductCategoryToProduct : ConventionInjection
{
    protected override bool Match(ConventionInfo c)
    {
        return c.TargetProp.Name.Equals(c.Source.Type.Name + c.SourceProp.Name) && c.SourceProp.Type.Equals(c.TargetProp.Type);
    }
}
```